# AWS PHP 7 Session got reset in every reset in

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, session, php-7

I am very new with AWS while deploying my project i found that session is not getting stored .

so with help of google and stack-overflow i was trying to resolve is and trying following code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
//ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1500);

 ini_set("session.save_handler", "files");
 $dir=getcwd() . '/ses'; //folder with 777 permission 
 ini_set('session.save_path', $dir);
 //ini_set('session.name', "name-session");
 ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
 ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
 //ini_set('session.serialize_handler', '');

$sId = session_id();if ($sId == '') { session_start(); }
print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['loggedIn']="swarna";
$_SESSION['name']=session_name();
$_SESSION['cookie_params']=session_get_cookie_params();
$_SESSION['cache_expire']=session_cache_expire();
$_SESSION['session_id']=session_id();
$_SESSION['maxlifetime']=ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
echo "<br> \n <pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r(scandir($dir));
echo "<br> \n </pre>";
```

but it didn't worked each time i refresh it is printing the first `print_r($_SESSION);` as empty and second one with different session id while expedition first one with same data which i have stored last execution .

```
Array ( )

Array
(
    [loggedIn] => swarna
    [name] => name-session
    [cookie_params] => Array
        (
            [lifetime] => 0
            [path] => /
            [domain] => 
            [secure] => 
            [httponly] => 
        )

    [cache_expire] => 180
    [session_id] => qip9hisbsh901gbpbjef4qe70c
    [maxlifetime] => 1440
)

Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => sess_2rkl7v7h593ih942i1k14o9s4d
    [3] => sess_4ccmmm0efq7quj26pm6r0ue9sn
    [4] => sess_8rvh2nd9n0ng4vtekevh6p26ef
    [5] => sess_lj4r99u9gf22ur935jr4gbcd97
    [6] => sess_qip9hisbsh901gbpbjef4qe70c
)
```

now i am using php7 in AWS   Amazon Linux 2 server . can any one guide me what to be done ? what is wrong their .

i have also tried

Comment: do you have load balancer ?

Comment: No -  load balancer is not their

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with AWS or ec2, I recommend you comment out all PHP into variables at the beginning of the script and always have session_start() at the beginning script

Comment: <?php session_start() ;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($GLOBALS);
print_r($_SESSION);
   $_SESSION['loggedIn']="swarna";
 $_SESSION['name']=session_name();
 $_SESSION['cookie_params']=session_get_cookie_params();
 $_SESSION['cache_expire']=session_cache_expire();
 $_SESSION['session_id']=session_id();
 $_SESSION['maxlifetime']=ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
 $_SESSION['session_save_path']=session_save_path();
echo "<br> \n <pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);

echo "<br> \n </pre>";

Comment: if i have load balancer  is their a way to resolve the issue ?

Comment: you need to enable stick sessions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html